# The difference between Chazal and Razal

Tags: hebrew, rabbis, etymology, acronyms

I have heard it said before that Chazal (חז"ל = חכמינו זכרונם לברכה; "our sages of blessed memory") refers to sages of the Mishna and Gemara, while Razal (רז"ל = רבנים/נו זכרונם לברכה; "our/the rabbonim of blessed memory") refers to Rishonim exclusively. I can't see that I have necessarily seen this distinction borne out by the literature, and *suspect*, though might be wrong, that the two are more-or-less interchangeable.

Can anybody clarify whether or not there is actually a distinction between these two terms, or whether or not anybody holds that there *should* be a distinction between them, and what that distinction might be?

Comment: I think it is *generally* that way, but there are definitely [exceptions](http://www.bhol.co.il/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=827412&forum_id=771)

Comment: @Yishai - For all I know, though, his "מקום אחר" is personal correspondence. Do you know of any printed texts that use Chazal to refer to acharonim?

Comment: Yes, it is a common attribution for that statement in Chassidic literature, even though the source for it is at earliest the Shiloh HaKadosh - an early Achron. However, it is an unusual formulation, and has been commented on.

Comment: The Tanya seems to use razal to refer to the Gemara.